# How can I hide a method in a child module but still use it from a parent module?

Tags: rust

I have a parent structure defined at my crate root that returns a structure that is defined in a module. I would like my parent structure to be the only thing that is capable of constructing the child structure, but I quickly run into understandable privacy and visibility issues with my naïve attempt:

```
#![feature(unsafe_destructor)]

mod child {
    pub struct Child(u8);

    impl Child {
        fn new(v: u8) -> Child { Child(v) }
    }
}

struct Parent;

impl Parent {
    fn child(&self) -> child::Child {
        child::Child::new(42)
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your `Child` struct must be public, if it is returned by a method of the `Parent`. Thus you need a

```
pub use child::Child;
```

Also, this will imply that the implementation of `Child` will be public as well, including the `new()` method. To prevent this, you can move it to an external helper method, that you will **not** reexport.

Also, the `Child` struct should have at least one private field, if you don't want it to be buildable with the `Child(42)` syntax.

In the end, you have something like that:

```
pub use child::Child;

mod child {
    pub struct Child {
        v: u8
    }

    pub fn build_child(v: u8) -> Child {
        Child { v: v }
    }

    impl Child {
        fn val(&self) -> u8 {
            self.v
        }
    }
}

struct Parent;

impl Parent {
    fn child(&self) -> Child {
        child::build_child(42)
    }
}
```

Here, `child::build_child(..)` is the only method able of creating a `Child` instance, and it is not visible outside of the module containing the definition of `Parent`.

Comment: If I still wished to expose `Child` as `child::Child`, is my best bet to rename `mod child` as `mod child_impl` and then `pub mod child { pub use super::child_impl::Child }`?

Comment: @Shepmaster I can't think of a better way. But it somehow is quite similar to the `Foo` vs `FooInternal` pattern we can see all over the libstd.

Comment: I did a quick grep for structs with `Internal` but didn't really see what you meant. Do you have a pointer handy for me to review?

Comment: @Shepmaster Oh, sorry, I mixed up. The term was `inner`. There are many structs that consist of a single field named `inner`. For example: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2b01a37ec38db9301239f0c0abcf3c695055b0ff/src/libstd/env.rs#L76